# How to convert JSON to a Dataframe in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have the below JSON format, I need to convert this to a dataframe in python. Please let me know, how to go about it.

JSON :

```
 User Patterns
[{"Jane": [{"Thermostat": 20, "Days": [1, 2], "Hour": 6, "Minute": 43}],  
"John": [{"Thermostat": 18, "Days": [1, 2], "Hour": 0, "Minute": 15}], 
"Jen": [{"Thermostat": 22, "Days": [1, 2], "Hour": 10, "Minute": 1}]}]
```

I want my dataframe to look like :

```
User    Thermostat   Days     Hour   Minute
Jane    20           [1,2]    6      43  
John    18           [1,2]    0      15 
Jen     22           [1,2]    10     1
```

Comment: You can use `pd.read_json(userpatterns)`

Comment: the variable where the JSON is stored is "th_pat". If I do pd.read_jso(th_pat). Its throwing me an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jstr = """[{"Jane": [{"Thermostat": 20, "Days": [1, 2], "Hour": 6, "Minute": 43}],  
"John": [{"Thermostat": 18, "Days": [1, 2], "Hour": 0, "Minute": 15}], 
"Jen": [{"Thermostat": 22, "Days": [1, 2], "Hour": 10, "Minute": 1}]}]"""

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {k: v[0] for k, v in json.loads(jstr)[0].items()}, 'index'
).rename_axis('User').reset_index()
```

[image]

---

If you want to split out the `Days` column

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {k: v[0] for k, v in json.loads(jstr)[0].items()}, 'index'
).rename_axis('User').reset_index()

df.drop('Days', 1).join(
    pd.DataFrame(df.Days.tolist()).rename(columns='Day{}'.format))
```

[image]

---

You can functionalize this:

```
def read_my_json(jstr):
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        {k: v[0] for k, v in json.loads(jstr)[0].items()}, 'index'
    ).rename_axis('User').reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you, but this JSON is stored in a variable called "th_pat". And for each experiement, the values of thermostat, day etc would change. Hence, how do I go about it

Comment: Sure, it worked. Thank you. I have a related question, can this be returned inside a function?. If I do so, I'm getting the following error:

NotImplementedError: Python Bridge conversion table not implemented for type [<type 'list'>]

Comment: I'm facing a minor issue again. For the column "Days", it has two values which is [1,2]. Hence while returning, its throwing an error as its unable to parse that list. 
How can I modify the code to make each of those values in a separate column, and also, the values might get increased, say [1,2,3] etc. 
So Is there a generic code, so each of those values, can be treated as a different column

Comment: @Anagha no problem.  Glad I could help.

Comment: How would we iterate through the JSON if each User had multiple records?